# tmux server does not start with ZSH returning "1;2c"

Tags: shell, zsh, tmux, oh-my-zsh

Have zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0) with 'oh-my-zsh' plugins.

Server log : https://gist.github.com/bigmyx/7055983ace63422bcb20

Client log :

```
got 207 from server
got 203 from server
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Both the question and self-answer are vague about what the original problem was. Please consider just deleting this question.

Comment: I am getting the same problem on a fresh installation... curious to figure out what the fix is.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be caused by a syntax error somewhere in your dotfiles. Common places to look: `.zshrc` (or `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, etc.), and of course `.tmux.conf`.

In my case I forgot to put quotes like so:
`DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT=true` should have been `DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT='true'`

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem. It's all about /dev/pts/ permission

Add your user to the tty group with the command  :

```
sudo usermod -a -G tty escaper
```

And then change permissions:

```
sudo chmod 730 /dev/pts
```

or whatever you want but with group writing perm.

Also if you get this problem after make chroot and mount /dev then you can mount dev/pts. So like this :

```
sudo mount --bind /dev/ /home/jail/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts/ /home/jail/dev/pts
```

Answer (score -2):

cleaning up my previous ~/.tmux.conf resolved the issue.

Comment: What exactly did you do to clean it up?